# Where are Command Line Tools for OS X 10.8.5 mountain lion after install?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I have command_line_tools_for_osx_mountain_lion_april_2014.dmg downloaded from Apple. I've installed it several times without error, but I see no trace of any of the tools in:

```
/Applications
/Libray
~/Applications
~/Library
```

However, gcc exists in /usr/bin.

I need the path to pass to

```
xcode-select --switch
```

but it is totally non-obvious.

```
locate Xcode
```

Turns up nothing.

Any ideas where Xcode is hiding?

Output from Command-L after install:

```
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-735
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: @(#)PROGRAM:Installer  PROJECT:Installer-618
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Hardware: MacBookPro5,2 @ 2.66 GHz (x 2), 8192 MB RAM
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/d9/gdvwf6dd01xgt6zhw_v6mvgr0000gn/T/
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: HOME=/Users/watson
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: USER=watson
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: LOGNAME=watson
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-TMiS1X/Listeners
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-A4W8lR/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-jYu50Q/Render
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Command Line Tools (Mountain Lion)  Installation Log
Jun 11 09:57:38 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Opened from: /Volumes/Command Line Tools (Mountain Lion) 1/Command Line Tools (Mountain Lion).mpkg
Jun 11 09:57:39 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Product archive /Volumes/Command Line Tools (Mountain Lion) 1/Command Line Tools (Mountain Lion).mpkg trustLevel=501
Jun 11 09:57:39 new-host.home Installer[55361]: External component packages (2) trustLevel=501
Jun 11 09:57:39 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Failed to open resource at path (null)
Jun 11 09:57:45 new-host.home Installer[55361]: InstallerStatusNotifications plugin loaded
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home runner[55365]: Administrator authorization granted.
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: ================================================================================
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: User picked Standard Install
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Choices selected for installation:
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]:     Upgrade: "Command Line Tools (Mountain Lion)"
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]:     Upgrade: "Command Line Tools (Mountain Lion)" at path "//"
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]:         DevSDK.pkg : com.apple.pkg.DevSDK : 0
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]:         DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg : com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI : 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: ================================================================================
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: It took 0.00 seconds to summarize the package selections.
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: location = file://localhost
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Command%20Line%20Tools%20(Mountain%20Lion)%201/Packages/DevSDK.pkg
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Command%20Line%20Tools%20(Mountain%20Lion)%201/Packages/DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Set authorization level to root for session
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Will use PK session
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Starting installation:
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Configuring volume "Macintosh HD"
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Preparing disk for local booted install.
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Free space on "Macintosh HD": 29.26 GB (29255061504 bytes).
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/d9/gdvwf6dd01xgt6zhw_v6mvgr0000gn/T//Install.55361egTqpF"
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: IFPKInstallElement (2 packages)
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Using authorization level of root for IFPKInstallElement
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home installd[55369]: installd: Starting
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home installd[55369]: installd: uid=0, euid=0
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <2 packages, destination=/>
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: packages=(
        "PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Command%20Line%20Tools%20(Mountain%20Lion)%201/Packages/DevSDK.pkg>",
        "PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Command%20Line%20Tools%20(Mountain%20Lion)%201/Packages/DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg>"
    )
Jun 11 09:57:59 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.apple.pkg.DevSDK (prefix path=/)
Jun 11 09:58:01 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI (prefix path=/)
Jun 11 09:58:02 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Command%20Line%20Tools%20(Mountain%20Lion)%201/Packages/DevSDK.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/4.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Jun 11 09:58:44 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Command%20Line%20Tools%20(Mountain%20Lion)%201/Packages/DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/4.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Jun 11 09:58:59 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: update_dyld_shared_cache -overlay /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/4.sandbox/Root
Jun 11 09:59:02 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: prevent user idle system sleep
Jun 11 09:59:02 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: suspending backupd
Jun 11 09:59:02 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Executing script "preinstall" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.W1Euwi/Scripts/com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI.50Gqsz
Jun 11 09:59:02 new-host.home install_monitor[55381]: Temporarily excluding: /Applications, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Jun 11 09:59:02 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/4.sandbox/Root (3 items) to /
Jun 11 09:59:24 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Executing script "postinstall" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.W1Euwi/Scripts/com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI.50Gqsz
Jun 11 09:59:24 new-host.home _securityagent[55395]: Running Install Scripts . . .
Jun 11 09:59:24 new-host.home _securityagent[55397]: Begin script: postflight
Jun 11 09:59:30 new-host.home _securityagent[55402]: End script: postflight
Jun 11 09:59:30 new-host.home _securityagent[55403]: 1 Install Scripts run.
Jun 11 09:59:32 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.apple.pkg.DevSDK to /private/var/db/receipts
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI to /private/var/db/receipts
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home installd[55369]: Installed "Command Line Tools (Mountain Lion)" ()
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home install_monitor[55381]: Re-included: /Applications, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: releasing backupd
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: allow user idle system sleep
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home installd[55369]: PackageKit: ----- End install -----
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Running install actions
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Removing temporary directory "/var/folders/d9/gdvwf6dd01xgt6zhw_v6mvgr0000gn/T//Install.55361egTqpF"
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Finalize disk "Macintosh HD"
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Notifying system of updated components
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: 
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: **** Summary Information ****
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]:   Operation      Elapsed time
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: -----------------------------
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]:        disk      0.01 seconds
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]:      script      0.01 seconds
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]:        zero      0.03 seconds
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]:     install      94.44 seconds
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]:     -total-      94.49 seconds
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: 
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: IFDInstallController A0C959F0 state = 5
Jun 11 09:59:33 new-host.home Installer[55361]: Displaying 'Install Succeeded' UI.
Jun 11 09:59:42 new-host.home UserEventAgent[253]: SUNotificationPlugin[uid=501]: trigger from periodic
Jun 11 09:59:42 new-host.home Software Update[55409]: SoftwareUpdate: shouldCheck=0 (i=603000.000000, l=2014-06-09 13:57:35 +0000, c=0) (dw=0, cdw=0, ac=1)
Jun 11 09:59:42 new-host.home Software Update[55409]: SoftwareUpdate: shouldCheck=0 (i=84600.000000, l=2014-06-11 13:57:35 +0000, c=1) (dw=0, cdw=0, ac=1)
Jun 11 09:59:42 new-host.home Software Update[55409]: SoftwareUpdateCheck: extra appstoreupdateagent params {
        SoftwareUpdateCount = 1;
    }
Jun 11 09:59:42 new-host.home Software Update[55409]: SUCheckService: sending result 1 to peer
Jun 11 09:59:42 new-host.home UserEventAgent[253]: SUNotificationPlugin[uid=501]: check done with result SUCheckServiceResultUpdatesAvailable
Jun 11 09:59:42 new-host.home UserEventAgent[253]: SUNotificationPlugin[uid=501]: Notifying appstoreupdateagent for user 501
Jun 11 09:59:42 new-host.home UserEventAgent[253]: SUNotificationPlugin[uid=501]: appstoreupdateagent notification sent
```

Comment: Correct. What I need is the xcode_folder_path.

Comment: Right. On my machine: $ `xcode-select --print-path`
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch <path-to-xcode>, or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.

Comment: There seem to be two questions here: 1. where are the command line tools, 2. how to select the version of Xcode to use. If you are interested in 2 then use `xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` and if needed change the path to match your system. I used the following two commands to switch the default Xcode: "sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app" and "sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app" depending on the version of Xcode I want to be the default.

Comment: There's only one question here. What I don't know is where the files to satisfy xcode-select are located. The impression I have is that the new version of command line tools may not sufficiently support the requirements that xcode-select expects. In other words, I may have to do a full Xcode install, when it seemed like the command line tools were sufficient. The xcode-select error that I'm getting is coming from `xcodebuild`
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch <path-to-xcode>, or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.

Comment: Assuming that you do not care if Xcode is installed then why are you interested in `xcode-select -switch`. If you are looking for a particular command line tool and have installed the command line tools then try: find / -name "tool_name" such as find / -name "llvm"

Comment: See: [man xcode-select](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html) When multiple Xcode applications are installed on a system (e.g. /Applications/Xcode.app, containing the  latest  Xcode, and /Applications/Xcode-DP.app containing a developer preview) use xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app to specify the Xcode that you wish  to use for command line developer tools.